# Meteor application not working in Chrome probably after Chrome got an update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor

I have an application built in Meteor. I run it locally and it is also deployed on a server. I just found out that the application is not running anymore on Chrome. I am not sure but probably the only difference is that my Chrome got an update today. The application works fine on Firefox and IE Edge and older IEs.
I looked in the console and I have these errors:

```
Exception in callback of async function: Error: Handler with name 'hookWithOptions' already exists.
    at MiddlewareStack._create (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:198:13)
    at MiddlewareStack.push (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:214:22)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:232:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?fa590de5090ceb4a42555b48562fd8f8e7035758:157:11)
    at MiddlewareStack.append (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:228:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:234:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?fa590de5090ceb4a42555b48562fd8f8e7035758:157:11)
    at MiddlewareStack.append (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?3370bd57ef7b310cca3f5dddb11b77fafdcfc1eb:228:5)
```

The error above is for the application which is on localhost.

The one which is deployed on the server and it is 2, 3 commits behind has these errors:

```
Exception in callback of async function: Error: Handler with name 'u' already exists.
    at o._create (http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:108:1599)
    at o.push (http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:108:1783)
    at http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:108:2033
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.A.each.A.forEach (http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:3:877)
    at o.append (http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:108:1963)
    at http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:108:2152
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.A.each.A.forEach (http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:3:877)
    at o.append (http://mynotes.work/6c81f4e47fc2bd6f405f6e71ba64f1376939052d.js?meteor_js_resource=true:108:1963)
```

I never thought that probably a browser update can break your app just like that. Does anyone knows what went wrong? In case you want to have a look, the link to the app is this: http://mynotes.work/

My current version of Chrome is this: 51.0.2704.84 m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this thread https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-error-handler-with-name-u-already-exists/23910/12 updating irron:middleware-stack helps.

*meteor update iron:middleware-stack* should solve this problem.

Comment: Some information about why this would help would be very nice.

Comment: Because I had the same problem and it helped?

Comment: Thanks maciekz! Updating the iron:middleware-stack was solving the problem at least for the application that is running on localhost. Probably updating the one deployed will solve the issue.